# “quantize result has too many digits for current context” error on save

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-models, decimal

I know this has been asked a number of times but somehow that didn't work out. I have this model field in model Song.

```
sent_score = models.DecimalField(default= 0.0,max_digits=4,decimal_places=2,blank=True)
```

In my view i update sent score the following ways.

```
song_item = Song.objects.get(id=id)
com_list = Comment.objects.filter(song_id=id)
com_count = com_list.count()
pos_comments = com_list.filter(sentiment='positive')
pos_count = pos_comments.count()
getcontext().prec = 2
sent_score = Decimal(pos_count)/Decimal(com_count)
```

However it still gives me this error:
`InvalidOperation: quantize result has too many digits for current context`

I also tried the quantize method in this way:

```
sc = Decimal(pos_count)/Decimal(com_count)
Decimal(sc).quantize(Decimal('12.12'), rounding = ROUND_DOWN)
song_item.sent_score = sc
song_item.save()
```

but it still gives the same error please tell me where am i going wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should **not use** `getcontext().prec = 2` as you did in your first try, because it changes the precision for everything, not just this one calculation.

The issue with your second example is, that `Decimal(sc).quantize(Decimal('12.12'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)` and even `sc.quantize(Decimal('12.12'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)` do not change `sc`.  Here is an example that works:

```
sc = Decimal(pos_count)/Decimal(com_count)
sc_adjusted = sc.quantize(Decimal('12.12'), rounding=ROUND_DOWN)
song_item.sent_score = sc_adjusted
song_item.save()
```